# Why does .NET Framework not use unsigned data types?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Array.Length an int, and not an uint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint)

Is there is a reason behind it .NET Framework not using unsigned data types?

Shouldn't I be adopting them in my code, but for example, the *Count* property of a List<> is an int. You can't have a negative count, so why shouldn't it be defined as a uint? Should I use only int's even though I know the count can not be negative?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658560/why-is-count-not-an-unsigned-integer and ...

Comment: I promise I did my homework and searched first. Maybe the wrong keyword combinations. Although I still do not think it answers the question as to why an unsigned int is not CLS compliant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant

Comment: Answered at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/09/02/50285.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unsigned numeric types are not [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx) so they should not be used for *any* API - especially the .NET framework.

Basically, CLS compliant code only utilizes types that are available in all .NET languages.  Some languages (like VB.NET) does not support unsigned numeric types.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the "why" question, does it?

Comment: @nikie it does. It just produces new question: why are they not CLS compliant.

Comment: @nikie - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant

Comment: @esac: ULong/UInteger were added with .NET 2.0

Answer (score 4):

The most basic answer is that the .NET framework designers chose to have signed integers part of the BCL (base class library) and CLS (common language syntax) specification, whereas they did not chose to make unsigned integers part of it.

For the reasoning behind *that* decision, ultimately you'd have to ask Microsoft. I would imagine that Eric Lippert could chime in here with a more thorough explanation.

It comes down to the following facts:

- You can't (or at least don't) have an implicit conversion between `int` and `uint`, meaning that conversions must be made explicitly using cast syntax
- It's best to avoid unnecessary casting syntax if it isn't adding to the readability of the code
- The upper bounds of `int` is sufficient for most numbers that we deal with in code

Putting those together means that the `int` type serves the purpose in most cases.

Comment: Actually more casting occurs when you need to use unsigned in a language trying to be CLSCompliant, e.g. C#. It's very inefficient when we know we're working with buffers containing bits and bytes and ushorts to have to continuously cast from int, e.g. adding two ushorts together is always evaluated as an integer. What I'd like to know is which lesser languages don't support the things most people want to do, i.e. unsigned/compact values.  I think we all agree duplicate names differing only by case is acceptable. The lesser languages should have to do more casting, not the normal ones.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned numbers are not CLS compliant because there are languages that do not support those types. I speak under correction, but VB.NET does not support unsigned types. This means that if you declare an public member as an unsigned type, then your assembly cannot be used from VB.NET or any other .NET language that does not support unsigned types.

Comment: VB.Net does support unsigned types; I'm not sure what languages don't.

Answer (score 1):

Some .NET aware languages do allow unsigned ints.  E.g. in C# you can use uint.

However, as they not CLS compliant if you expose them outside of your assembly then you might find that other developers using a different language will have problems using your classes.

So in summary... Feel free to use them, but keep them zipped up inside your classes using either the private or internal keywords.