# Why is String.Length signed?

Tags: c#, .net, unsigned, signed, string-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does .Net Framework not use unsigned data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935165/why-does-net-framework-not-use-unsigned-data-types)

In [The C# Programming Language (Covering C# 4.0) (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765), 1.3 Types and Variables, Page 9.

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) says;

> Hooray for byte being an unsigned type! The fact that in Java a byte
>   is signed (and with no unsigned equivalent) makes a lot of
>   bit-twiddling pointlessly error-prone. It’s quite possible that we
>   should all be using uint a lot more than we do, mind you: I’m sure
>   many developers reach for int by default when they want an integer
>   type. The framework designers also fall into this category, of course:
>   Why should String.Length be signed?

When I decompile [String.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx);

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of characters in the current <see cref="T:System.String"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of characters in the current string.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public int Length { [SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] get; }
```

Also in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx);

> The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this
>   instance, **not the number of Unicode characters**. The reason is that a
>   Unicode character might be represented by more than one Char.

It returns the number of character objects in the current string. Why does `String.Length` return `Int32` when there already is a type called `UInt32`? What is the point of the `signed-unsigned byte` and `String.Length`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Int32` is widely considered to be the "general-purpose" integer in the .NET framework.  If you need a general number that is not fractional, `Int32` is what you reach for first.  You would only use one of the unsigned types if you had a specific reason to do so.

Using `int` for all  Count properties creates a consistent API, and allows for the possibility of using -1 as a flag value (which some APIs in the framework do).

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/09/02/50285.aspx:

> *The general feeling among many of us is that the vast majority of programming is done with signed types.  Whenever you switch to
>   unsigned types you force a mental model switch (and an ugly cast).  In
>   the worst cast you build up a whole parallel world of APIs that take
>   unsigned types.*

Comment: Well, that sadly is not the correct answer ;) See mine ;)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but your answer doesn't really invalidate mine.

Comment: +1 for karma :-) I think this is a reasonable justification for use of `Int32`. Having said that, TomTom's answer is probably what actually happened in practice, so I voted for both of you.

Comment: Unless either of you have some reference to an actual Microsoft employee stating the reason that they choose to use this, we can only ever theorize what possible reasons might have been.

Comment: Even more important than the fact that -1 can be used as a flag value is that there's no question about how subtraction of `Int32` values should work.  Given variables `x` and `y` of type `UInt32`, there are three plausible meanings a language might assign to `x-y`: yield a `UInt32` holding the result mod 4294967296, yield an `Int64` holding the arithmetically-correct result, or yield a `UInt32` which holds the arithmetic result when positive and throw an exception otherwise; the only interpretation which would avoid run-time surprises would require promotion to `Int64`, but that would make...

Comment: ...`UInt32` types rather burdensome to work with.

Answer (score 11):

Because all .NET core objects are CLS compliant. And CLS has no unsigned data types.

Check

[Why are unsigned int's not CLS compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant)

for the details.

Comment: Well, not quite. `byte` is CLS compliant, and it's unsigned.

Comment: Yes. This is about the language independent part, and somehow not all languages can deal with them. That is funny, though, as the unified type system otoh - well, it is complex. Big turnaround, it is a pain, but that is how it is ;)