# Usage of unsigned return types on public methods

Tags: c#

Recently, I came across a statement that C# does not allow unsigned integer types as the return type **on** **public** **methods**. I am unable to understand why. Please explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935165/why-does-net-framework-not-use-unsigned-data-types

Comment: I viewed that question earlier, but my question is different. Please review in order to get clarification.

Comment: I think you can easily find your answer by trying to create a method with a return type of `uint` in `C#`. then you won't need to ask **why** cause you will see there is no such thing.

Comment: i tried .. u can't create a " public uint method1(){} " in c#

Comment: @HiteshSikka [Really ?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLNLIq)