# Why does HashSet<T>.Count return an int instead of uint?

Tags: c#, count, int, hashset

I was wondering when working with a `HashSet<T>` why the property `HashSet<T>.Count` returns a value of type `int` instead of `uint`.

Please correct me when I am wrong, as far as I know it's not possible to have a negative number of entries in a `HashSet<T>`. So when the smallest returned Count is `0` a `uint` value would make much more sense in my view.

Does anyone have a clue on this?
Or are there other reasons why it's a return value with typeof `int`?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that's because [`uint` is not CLS compliant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333/1180426), and `HashSet<>` is in a standard platform library.

Comment: Thanks @PatrykĆwiek that makes sense.

Comment: Some things ARE `int` and your code would be filled with casts between the two. Java doesn't even bother to include `uint`. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658560 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301

Comment: I think this applies to many many different properties as well, for instance also `List<T>.Count` or `Array.Length`, it´s not specific to `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: I did not found an already asked question to this specific topic. Maybe it was my fault that I did not searched for a more general kind of question (which is marked as duplicate).