# Should I use uint in C# for values that can't be negative?

Tags: c#, integer

I have just tried implementing a class where numerous length/count properties, etc. are `uint` instead of `int`. However, while doing so I noticed that it's actually painful to do so, like as if no one actually wants to do that.

Nearly everything that hands out an integral type returns an `int`, therefore requiring casts in several points. I wanted to construct a `StringBuffer` with its buffer length defaulted to one of the fields in that class. Requires a cast too.

So I wondered whether I should just revert to `int` here. I'm certainly not using the entire range anyway. I just thought since what I'm dealing with there simply *can't* be negative (if it was, it'd be an error) it'd be a nice idea to actually use `uint`.

P.S.: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint) and this at least explains why the framework itself always uses `int` but even in own code it's actually cumbersome to stick to `uint` which makes me think it apparently isn't really wanted.

Comment: Also see [why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

While strictly you should use `uint` for variables that hold non-negative integer you have come across one of reasons why it's not always practicable.

In this case I don't think the reduction in readability that comes with having to do casts is worth it.

Comment: Its hard to say  , i dont think the casts reduce legability a lot  for  just indexers and you can create a wrapper. And ints that become negative are painful and expensive bugs.

Comment: If you have to create a wrapper for an int then you have more than readability problems :)

Answer (score 68):

I'll add to the other answers also that using uint as type of a public field, property, method, parameter, and so on, is a violation of the Common Language Specification rules and to be avoided when possible.

Comment: And I got burnt by Microsoft strictly following that. It turns out that IntPtr should have had a uint constructor.

Comment: I would also add if they supported natural numbers  eg  this type is value 0 to 6 they could eliminate all array bounds checking , a massive 5-10% performance boost .

Comment: Do you concurr with the statement above, Mr. Lippert?

Comment: @AgentFire: The statement makes a claim that if someone did something, that would cause a specific performance improvement. I have no ability to evaluate counterfactual claims; if you want to know if that claim is true, ask user1496062 what justifies their claim, not me; I'm not the one making the unsupported claim.

Comment: @EricLippert that's one of your shortest longest "i dont know"s, isnt it :p

Answer (score 4):

My personal feeling is that you should probably just stick to int. It's not worth adding a cast to pretty much every single property access just to reclaim a numeric range that .NET's unlikely to let you use anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A negative value is often used to signal an error condition, and the size of a operation is often returned by a function call; a negative value may therefore signal error without resorting to an exception mechanism.

Also note that .NET often builds upon straight C libraries, therefore it is sensible to continue this convention. If you require a larger index space you can break the convention for different error signalling mechanism.

Comment: .NET's pretty consistent with throwing exceptions rather than returning error codes. The -1 return is not a common sight in managed code.

Comment: agreed, but we are talking about a design convention that is prevalent throughout windows technologies (in addition to exceptions where they are supported) -- those parts of the .NET library that interface with low level code have to translate between CRT error codes and exceptions -- it is sort of understandable why they bring forward the convention of int's rather than uint's.

Comment: @HassanSyed still, if some winapi returns negative value, the framework will still throw it's own exception, wrapping everything into a neat shell, so that argument doesn't rly apply here.

Answer (score 3):

Using an int is also helpful to detect integer overflow in operations.

Comment: Not 100% accurate, if it so overflowed that it reaches zero. Again, there is a overflow protection enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, the drawback of using `uint` is that it obscures error conditions.  The equivalents of the following code aren't as nice:

```
if (len < 0)
    terminate_program("length attained impossible value.");
```

Of course your programs should not miscalculate anything to begin with, but I feel they also should be written to rapidly detect numerical erros without propagation.  In the case where a MaxValue of 2^31 is enough, I say use `int` along with proper use of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert()` and corresponding error-checks as exemplified above.

If you do use `uint` use it along with `checked` to prevent underflow and get the same results.  However I have found that check is a little bit difficult to apply to existing code that uses casts for some purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that a value is positive, a better way is probably just by using assert (note this is just a debugging technique - you should ensure that this never occurs in the final code).

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Debug.Assert (i > 0);
```

Comment: See also the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't swim upstream if you don't have to.  Not litering your code with casts makes your code more readable.  Further, if your possible values fit within an int, then using an int is not a problem.

If you're afraid you might overflow an int, then there by all means.. but don't prematurely optimize.

I would say the improved readability of minimizing casts outweighs the slightly elevated risk of a bug with using int.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use it only if you wont need to cast from uint to int or the other way around back and forth.

its ok to cast but, if the integer you're casting to uint is a minus value,
then casting it to uint will set the uint to the maximum value possible ( 2^32),
which could lead into some bugs.