# In C# should I use uint or int for values that are never supposed to be negative?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, code-contracts, uint32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use uint in C# for values that can’t be negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013116/should-i-use-uint-in-c-for-values-that-cant-be-negative)

Suppose that the `MaxValue` of (roughly :) ) 2^31 vs 2^32 does not matter.
On one hand, using `uint` seems nice because it is self-explanatory, it indicates (and promises?) that some value may never be negative. However, `int` is more common, and a cast is often inconvenient. One can just use int and always supplement it with code contracts (everyone has moved to .Net 4.0 by now, right?) Standard libraries do use `int` for `Length` and `Size` properties, even though those should never be negative. So, is it obvious to you that `int` is better than `uint` most of the time, or is it more complicated?

Please ask questions if you find that this question is not clearly stated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Yup, looks like a dupe. However, and extra small question: could you give me a good example of how to supplement the properties / functions with code contracts / assert statements in this particular case when value may not be negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here for the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013116/should-i-use-uint-in-c-for-values-that-cant-be-negative).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No. You may want to implement as below.

```
private int _length;
public int Length
{
    get { return _length; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Length must be always positive. Please make sure the value is positive value.");
        }
        this._length = value;
    }
}
```