# using uint vs int

Tags: c#

I have observed for a while that C# programmers tend to use int everywhere, and rarely resort to uint. But I have never discovered a satisfactory answer as to why.

If interoperability is your goal, uint shouldn't appear in public APIs because not all CLI languages support unsigned integers. But that doesn't explain why int is so prevalent, even in internal classes. I suspect this is the reason uint is used sparingly in the BCL.

In C++, if you have an integer for which negative values make no sense, you choose an unsigned integer.

This clearly signifies that negative numbers are not allowed or expected, and the compiler will do some checking for you. I also suspect in the case of array indices, that the JIT can easily drop the lower bounds check.

However, when mixing int and unit types, extra care and casts will be needed.

Should uint be used more? Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint

Comment: Just thaught I had a deja vu :D , nearly exact the same question has been asked short while ago.

Comment: As for lower bounds checks (in case you need to write your own) you can replace `if (i < 0 || i >= length)` with `if (unchecked((uint)i) >= length)`. Resulting IL will have one (branch) instruction less in total and will give approximately the same performance (infinitesimally faster). Personally I love it simply because it scratches my itch against checking lower bounds. Others are likely to argue against it due to "unchecked", but I argue that this is a very good line for learning its meaning because it's simple and instantly clear from context what the purpose is = helps the reader learn.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the above is optimal on 64bit builds since it will perform the comparison with 64 bits. For 32bit builds `if (unchecked((uint)i) >= unchecked((uint)length))` gives better performance. This does however look _very_ convoluted, and the 64bit compare is still more performant than the standard double-branching bounds-check on a 32bit build so I can't really recommend this in any reasonable situation. (I'm mostly mentioning it to point out that a 64-bit compare is used otherwise - which might be useful information to some.)

Comment: Gentlemen, I contend that your primary opinion base is no good. If there is an objective answer possible, I for one, would like to hear it. I'm all for changing my practices for benefit.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your observation of why `uint` isn't used in the BCL is the main reason, I suspect.

UInt32 is not CLS Compliant, which means that it is wholly inappropriate for use in public APIs.  If you're going to be using uint in your private API, this will mean doing conversions to other types - and it's typically easier and safer to just keep the type the same.

I also suspect that this is not as common in C# development, even when C# is the only language being used, primarily because it is not common in the BCL.  Developers, in general, try to (thankfully) mimic the style of the framework on which they are building - in C#'s case, this means trying to make your APIs, public and internal, look as much like the .NET Framework BCL as possible.  This would mean using uint sparingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013116/should-i-use-uint-in-c-for-values-that-cant-be-negative is a question that deals with a similar topic

Answer (score 84):

`int` is shorter to type than `uint`.

Comment: I suspect this is pretty close to the truth.  Why use `uint` when 99% of the time (in my experience) `int` will suffice?

Comment: Yeah, I've never had a reason to use a `uint`.  And, if I need to store a larger number I just use a `long`.  It is nice to be able to use -1 as an error or default value.

Comment: @Justin: "Magic numbers" like -1 are not a good idea, in general.  Switching to long means using 2x memory for no reason, as well...  "unit" definitely is valuable, provided you don't need to interact with other APIs.

Comment: I never feel comfortable using an `int` to index an array, because I'm not ever going to have a negative index. Seems blindly obvious that a `uint` should be used in this case.

Comment: Not to mention, more readable. If you ever pass your code/algorithms for someone else to read that may be less experienced than you, using lots of `uint` can hang them up a bit. `int` is perfectly acceptable to use in all situations where you control the range it will take.

Comment: I rather enjoyed the "old days" of Delphi's range types.  That really tripped people's triggers when an array can be from 5..6.

Comment: @MarkH Completely agreed, but when doing a reverse iteration it can be useful in the form of: `for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { }`. Doing that with a uint will result in an overflow exception or worse, an infinite loop.

Comment: @Aidiakapi I agree. That actually happened to me once when I switched an int to uint because I needed one extra bit of precision. Caused an infinite loop because it was used in a reverse-loop somewhere in the code.

Comment: @MarkH In .NET array CAN be created with negative lower bounds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-array-createinstance(system-type-system-int32()-system-int32())

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, your source explicitly states that CreateInstance will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if any of the indices are < 0.

Comment: It doesn't say so. It says that it throws if Any value in LENGTHS is less than zero. It does support LOWERBOUNDS lower than 0. Try it for yourself. Check this code. This is a multidimensional array with only one dimension with 10 elements starting in index -4 with a value in the index -3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/edWcp.png

Comment: If someone wants to see an example of where uint shows its value (pun intended), check out this GitHub of probabilistic data structures where the idea is to use primitives that can save memory space but optimize the addressable data structure size: https://github.com/mattlorimor/ProbabilisticDataStructures

Answer (score 21):

Normally `int` will suffice. If you can satisfy all of the following conditions, you can use `uint`:

- It is not for a public API (since `uint` is not CLS compliant).
- You don't need negative numbers.
- You (might) need the additional range.
- You are *not* using it in a comparison with `< 0`, as that is never `true`.
- You are *not* using it in a comparison with `>= 0`, as that is never `false`.

The last requirement is often forgotten and will introduce bugs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0) return;
    uint last = (uint)(args.Length - 1);

    // This will eventually throw an IndexOutOfRangeException:
    for (uint i = last; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

1) Bad habit. Seriously. Even in C/C++.

Think of the common `for` pattern:

```
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    foo(i);
```

There's absolutely no reason to use an integer there. You will never have negative values. But almost everyone will do a simple loop that way, even if it contains (at least) two other "style" errors.

2) `int` is perceived as the native type of the machine.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer `uint` to `int` unless a negative number is actually in the range of acceptable values. In particular, accepting an `int` param but throwing an `ArgumentException` if the number is less than zero is just silly--use a `uint`!

I agree that `uint` is underused, and I encourage everyone else to use it more.

Comment: It is very dangerous to accept only uints and not check the bounds. If someone passes a negative value, the CLR will interpret it as a large int, meaning for -1 you get uint.maxvalue. This is not desired behaviour.

Comment: @Henri: C# doesn't have an implicit conversion from int to uint, so there is no "If someone passes a negative value".  Of course a bounds check on the upper limit is still appropriate (but now you only need one check instead of two).

Answer (score 1):

I program at a lower level application layer where ints rarely get above 100, so negative values are not an issue (e.g. for i < myname.length() type stuff) it's just an old C habit - and shorter to type as mentioned above. However, in some cases, when interfacing to hardware where I'm dealing with event flags from devices, the uint is important in cases where a flag may use the left (highest) most bit.

Honestly, for 99.9% of my work I could easily use ushort, but int, you know, sounds sounds a lot better than ushort.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a Direct3D 10 wrapper in C# & need to use uint if I want to create very large vertex buffers. Large buffers in the video card can not be represented with a signed int.

UINT is very useful & is silly to say otherwise. If anyone thinks just because they have never needed to use uint no one else will, you are wrong.

Comment: That's a good case where you can take advantage of the wider range.

Answer (score 0):

I think a big part of the reason is that when C first came out most of the examples used `int` for brevity's sake. We rejoiced at not having to write `integer` like we did with Fortran and Pascal, and in those days we routinely used them for mundane things like array indices and loop counters. Unsigned integers were special cases for large numbers that needed that last extra bit. I think it's a natural progression that C habits continued into C# and other new languages like Python.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages (e.g. many versions of Pascal) regard unsigned types as representing numeric quantities; an operation between an unsigned type and a signed type of the same size will generally be performed as though the operands were promoted to the next larger type (in some such languages, the largest type has no unsigned equivalent, so such promotion will always be possible).

Other languages (e.g. C) regard N-bit unsigned types as a group which wraps around modulo 2^N.  Note that subtracting N from a member of such a group doesn't represent numerical subtraction, but rather yields the group member which, when N is added to it, would yield the original.  Arguably, certain operations involving mixtures of signed and unsigned values don't really make sense and should perhaps have been forbidden, but even code which is sloppy with its specifications of things like numeric literals will usually work, and code has been written which mixes signed and unsigned types and, despite being sloppy, does work, that the spec isn't apt to change any time soon.

It's a lot easier to work exclusively with signed types than to work out all the intricacies of interactions between signed and unsigned types.  Unsigned types are useful when decomposing large numbers out of smaller pieces (e.g. for serialization) or for reconstituting such numbers, but in general it's better to simply use signed numbers for things that actually represent quantities

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably an old thread but I wanted to give some clarification.

Lets take an int8 you can store –128 to 127 and it uses 1 byte that is a total of 127 positive numbers.
When you use an int8 one of the bits is used for the negative numbers -128.
When you use a Uint8 you give the negative numbers to the positive so this allows you to use 255 positive numbers with the same amount of storage 1 byte.
The only draw back is the you have now lost the capability to use negative values.
Another problem with this is not all programming languages and databases support this.
The only reason you would use this in my opinion is when you need to be efficient in like gaming programming and you have to store large non negative numbers. 
This is why not many programs use this it.

The main reason is storage is not a problem and you can't use it flexibly with other software, plugins, Database, or Api's. Also for example a bank would need negative numbers to store money etc.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just laziness. C# is inherently a choice for development on desktops and other machines with relatively much resources.

C and C++, however, has deep roots in old systems and embedded systems where memory is sparse, so programmers are used to think carefully what datatype to use.
C# programmers are lazy, and since there are enough resources in general, nobody really optimizes memory usage (in general, not always of course). Event if a byte would be sufficient, a lot of C# programmers, including me, just use int for simplicity. Moreover, a lot of API functions accept ints, so it prevents casting.

I agree that choosing the correct datatype is good practice, but I think the main motivation is laziness.

Finally, choosing an integer is more mathematically correct. Unsigned ints don't exist in math (only natural numbers). And since most programmers have a mathematical background, using an integer is more natural.

Comment: I would not say it's laziness, although laziness has it's merits. It's more that most of the time, I just don't care enough about the int/uint thing, to waste my brain cycles on such a decision, and just go with the int. Hardware is cheep, programmers can be expensive.

Comment: Programmers are lazy. That's a bad thing. Raymond would say that programmers hate to pay their taxes!

Comment: I would be the first to admin that us C# programmers are lazy but that isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @Lorenzo, I wrote an article in university, stating that a lazy programmer is a good programmer. Mostly it was about optimizing for programmer time instead of machine time.

Comment: Hmm, most of the programmers-imputable bugs I've ever seen (or done) are caused by laziness...

Comment: follow MS recommendation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/uint

Comment: Google summarizer is taking this answer as the page summery.