# c#: Convert an int into the smallest byte array it will fit into

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like an elegant, efficient means of taking any unsigned integer and converting it into the smallest byte array it will fit into.  For example:

```
250 = byte[1]
2000 = byte[2]
80000 = byte[3]
```

so that I can write:

```
var foo = getBytes(bar);
```

and `foo` will be of different lengths depending on the value of `bar`.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, as an extension method:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this int value) {
     var bytes = Enumerable
                     .Range(0, sizeof(int))
                     .Select(index => index * 8)
                     .Select(shift => (byte)((value >> shift) & 0x000000ff))
                     .Reverse()
                     .SkipWhile(b => b == 0x00)
                     .ToArray();
     return bytes;
}
```

Then:

```
int j = 2000;
var bytes = j.ToByteArray();
Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length);
for(int index = 0; index < bytes.Length; index++) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", bytes[index]);
}
```

Gives:

```
2
0x07
0xd0
```

And replacing `j = 2000` by `j = 80000` in the above gives

```
3
0x01
0x38
0x80
```

And replacing `j = 2000` by `j = 250` in the above gives

```
1
0xfa
```

Comment: Elegant... I like it.  How well do you think it will perform?

Comment: It's definitely not the fastest, but unless you're doing this in a very tight loop, it's probably fast enough. Only *you* can know if this meets your performance requirements.

Comment: @Jeremy - Can you explain what makes this answer more elegant than the one posted by thecoop?  What does 'elegant' mean when it comes to code?

Comment: I would say doing blocks of if statements to explicitly cover every possibility is not elegant... it's effective, and may be fast, but I don't think it's elegant.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I see that phrase a lot when it comes to code and was just pondering what exactly is "elegant code"?  Is it code that is short and easy to maintain?  Does it have to be short?  I presume it must perform well to be considered elegant.  What are the traits that make code elegant?

Answer (score 2):

There's no single method you can use, but you can do it quite easily (warning - not tested)

```
byte[] bytes;

if ((i & 0xffffff00)==0) {
    bytes = new byte[] { (byte)i };
}
else if ((i & 0xffff0000)==0) {
    bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(i & 0xff), (byte)((i & 0xff00) >> 8) };
}
else if ((i & 0xff000000)==0) {
    bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(i & 0xff), (byte)((i & 0xff00) >> 8), (byte)((i & 0xff0000) >> 16) };
}
else {
    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
}
```

Comment: bleh... yeah but that's what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm hoping for something a bit more elegant than that sort of brute force method.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you all the bytes:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(uint bar)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(bar).Reverse().SkipWhile(c => c == 0).Reverse().ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: well, I'll want the bits in there too, but this is clean.  I like it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs The second one will do what you want

Comment: -1, sorry, but the first returns 1 if the `int` is 0xff000000 (you want all 4 bytes in this instance). The second will return all 4 bytes, whether needed or not. Sorry again mate.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier The last one will work for your example? It's not that big of deal to make it trim the size of the array if needed

Comment: @OskarKjellin the second one will not work, this will bring back a 4-byte array per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs See my update. This will remove all zeroes from the end

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I think the version works for all cases, pretty fast too

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just hard code the boundary points, but if you want a more dynamic approach, you could use something like this:

```
byte[] getBytes(uint bar) {
    if (bar == 0) return new byte[0];

    return getBytes(bar / 256)
            .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((byte)(bar % 256), 1))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Be aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095805/uint-vs-int-in-c-sharp

Comment: interesting, but negatives are out of scope for the question: As I recall from my comp sci days, a negative 32-bit int will always be 4 bytes.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Most often you would just throw an exception in that case

Comment: Well that may not be an error condition; my point was, I will know how long that byte array needs to be (always 4) for every negative int32, but I may not need/ want 4 bytes for a positive int when one will do.  That's why I'm saying it's out of my question's scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is appropriate for long type as well (the only change is "byte?[4]" to "byte?[8]", and declaration of course).

```
static byte[] ToArray(int num) 
{
    byte?[] b = new byte?[4];
    int i = 0;

    do b[i++] = (byte)num;
    while ((num = num >> 8) > 0);

    byte[] result = new byte[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        result[j] = b[j].Value;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private byte[] GetBytes(int number)
{            
    if (number < 0) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Can not be less than zero", "number");
    }

    int numberOfBits = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        numberOfBits++;
        number = number >> 1;
    }

    int reminder = 0;
    int numberofBytes = Math.DivRem(numberOfBits, 8, out reminder);
    numberofBytes = reminder > 0 ? numberofBytes + 1 : numberofBytes;
    return new byte[numberofBytes];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be reasonably fast, and it only allocates exactly as much space as it needs to.

```
static byte[] getBytes(long a)
{
    int k=0;
    for (long b=a; b!=0; b>>=8) k++;
    byte[] res = new byte[k];
    for (k=0; a!=0; a>>=8)
        res[res.Length-(++k)] = (byte)(a&0xFF);
    return res;
}
```