# Why does the .NET framework tend to use 'int' instead of unsigned integers?

Tags: .net

There are many places in the .NET framework where int seems to be used instead of uint where one would never expect a negative number.

For example .Take() in LINQ takes an integer.
Port in IPEndpoint or other network classes is a signed integer.
And so on.

Is there a reason for this 'loose' typing?

Comment: related : [Using uint vs int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095805/using-uint-vs-int)

Comment: also related on software engineering : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306677/should-i-avoid-using-unsigned-int-in-c