# Why do we use int when memory is only positive

Tags: c#, c++

I was wondering why do we use integers to get addresses in memory while memory addresses can only be positive? Why don't we use unsigned integers? 
For example: 
in C#, why do we have IntPtr, why not UIntPtr? 
Arrays also have a limitation of Int32.Max. Still, why not unsigned since index can only be >= 0? 
Also, in C++, a lot of codes assign a pointer address to ints, and not uints, is there a reason behind it? Is it bad practice?

Thank you!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint

Comment: @MatsPetersson I considered closing too, but decided against it because none of the reasons in the answers to that other question apply to C++, and the OP asks about both C# and C++. Are you sure closing is appropriate at this point? (I understand it's a judgement call, if you still feel it's appropriate I won't re-open.)

Comment: In C# there is [UIntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure that there is THAT much to answer... Using signed or unsigned makes little difference when dealing with pointers (unless you use the integer type for comparison, AND have a system where pointers cross the 31st or 63rd bit...)

Comment: Then why do we never use it? All the .NET Framework implementations are done using IntPtr... About closing the post, I do understand there is a duplicate; however not all the answers are on the other post. Thank you :)