# Why does Stream.Write not take a UInt?

Tags: c#, .net, method-signature, cls-compliant

It seems highly illogical to me that [Stream.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) uses `int`, instead of `UInt`... Is there an explanation other than "legacy" code for this fact? Would any one want to write `-1` bytes?!?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unsigned types are not CLS-compliant, hence `Stream.Write`  doesn't use `uint` for offset and count.

See: [uint (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx)

> The uint type is not CLS-compliant. Use int whenever possible.

There is an old article: [Why we don't have unsigned types in the CLS by Brad Abrams (**2 Sep 2003**)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/09/02/50285.aspx) that explains the reason:

> However there is one issue that keeps coming up:  Why did we not allow
>   unsigned types (UInt32 and the like) in the CLS?
>
> Well, there are really **two answers** to this question.  **At the first
>   level some languages (such as VB.NET) do not offer full support for
>   unsigned types.**  For example you can’t have unsigned literals in
>   VB.NET….  But to be fair that is not a completely satisfying answer
>   because when we started the CLS you could not subclass in VB.NET
>   either, but we extended that language to support what we knew people
>   would want.  We could have done the same thing with unsigned types. 
>   But we didn’t.  Why not?  Well, that gets a deeper reason.  In fact
>   the same reason why early betas of the C# language did not support
>   unsigned types (no ushort, uint and the like).
>
> The general feeling
>   among many of us is that the **vast majority of programming is done
>   with signed types.  Whenever you switch to unsigned types you force a
>   mental model switch (and an ugly cast).**  In the worst cast you build
>   up a whole parallel world of APIs that take unsigned types.  The value
>   of avoiding the “< 0” check is not worth the inclusion of generics in
>   the CLS.

*(Note that newer version of VB.Net (VB 8 onwards) supports unsigned types)*.

One more thing *(probably unrelated)* to add, [`Stream.Write` implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1781) has  checks for negative values:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public override void Write(byte[] array, int offset, int count) {
    if (array==null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Buffer"));
    if (offset < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    if (array.Length - offset < count)
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidOffLen"));
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [uint MSDN only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx)

> The uint type is not CLS-compliant. Use int whenever possible.

So `Stream.Write` uses int for offset and count.

The [reasons given by ShuggyCoUk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301/why-is-array-length-an-int-and-not-an-uint) makes it more clear:

> - uint is not CLS compliant, thus making a built in type (array) dependent on it would have been problematic
> - The runtime as
>     originally designed prohibits any object on the heap occupying more
>     than 2GB of memory. Since the maximum sized array that would less than
>     or equal to this limit would be new byte[int.MaxValue] it would be
>     puzzling to people to be able to generate positive but illegal array
>     lengths.
>
>   - Note that this limitation has been [somewhat removed in the 4.5 release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx),
>       though the standard Length as int remains.
> - Historically C# inherits
>     much of its syntax and convention from C and C++. In those arrays are
>     simply pointer arithmetic so negative array indexing was possible
>     (though normally illegal and dangerous). Since much existing code
>     assumes that the array index is negative this would have been a factor
> - On a related note the use of signed integers for array indexes in C/C++ means that interop with these languages and unmanaged functions
>     would require the use of ints in those circumstances anyway, which may
>     confuse due to the inconsistency.
> - The BinarySearch implementation
>     (a very useful component of many algorithms) relies on being able to
>     use the negative range of the int to indicate that the value was not
>     found **and** the location at which such a value should be inserted to
>     maintain sorting.
> - When operating on an array it is likely that you
>     would want to take a negative offset of an existing index. If you used
>     an offset which would take you past the start of the array using unit
>     then the wrap around behaviour would make your index possibly legal
>     (in that it is positive). With an int the result would be illegal (but
>     safe since the runtime would guard against reading invalid memory)

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, unsigned integers are [not part of the Common Language Specification (CLS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhc3fa7f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[MSDN entry for uint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx):

> The uint type is not CLS-compliant. Use int whenever possible.

Thus Microsoft used `int` here instead of `uint` in the interests of CLS-compliancy.